# SQL Connection - DataReaders under a same connection aren't bringing different results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Have written a code in C# for connecting two SQL servers to get results for 6 different queries with two connections, three databases and six queries.
Issue: The first query and the last three queries are bringing the results properly, but the 2nd and 3rd queries are bring the result of query 1.
Please help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace TOCOrderStats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection con1, con2;
            SqlDataReader dr1, dr2, dr3, dr4, dr5, dr6;
            SqlCommand cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4, cmd5, cmd6;

            con1 = new SqlConnection("Server=SSE-SQL-CLUSTER;Database=wlr3crm;Trusted_Connection=True;");         
            con2 = new SqlConnection("Server=WLR3-SQL-CLUSTE;Database=wlr3crm_orange;Trusted_Connection=True;");

            con1.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection 1 Open");
            try
            {
                string query1 = "select servicetype, ordertype, count(servicetype) as ordercount from ordermaster "+
"where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created_date, 111) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 111) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),"+
"created_date, 111) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) group by servicetype,ordertype;";

                Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery 1 Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery1.txt isn't NULL");
                }
                cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con1);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd 1 initiated");

                dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("dr1 executed");

                if (dr1 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader1NULL.txt","DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DR1 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr1.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR1 read begins");
                    string SSE1results_column1 = "";
                    string SSE1results_column2 = "";
                    string SSE1results_column3 = "";

                    SSE1results_column1 = dr1["servicetype"].ToString();
                    SSE1results_column2 = dr1["ordertype"].ToString();
                    SSE1results_column3 = dr1["ordercount"].ToString();

                    string SSE1results_rows = SSE1results_column1 + "#" + SSE1results_column2 + "#" + SSE1results_column3 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query1 " + SSE1results_rows);

                    if (SSE1results_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result1.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#" + "NULL3" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result in NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result1.txt", SSE1results_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query1 and written to file");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR1 ends");

                dr1.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR1 closes");
                cmd1.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd1 disposes");

                //###################################################

                string query2 = "select servicetype, ordertype, count(servicetype) as ordercount from"+
"ordermaster where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created_date, 111) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-2, 111) and "+
"CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created_date, 111) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 111) group by servicetype,ordertype;";

                Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery 2 Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery2.txt isn't NULL");
                }

                cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con1);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd2 initiated");
                dr2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("DR2 executed");

                if (dr2 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader2NULL.txt", "DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DataReader2 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR2 read begins");
                    string SSE2results_column1 = "";
                    string SSE2results_column2 = "";
                    string SSE2results_column3 = "";

                    SSE2results_column1 = dr2["servicetype"].ToString();
                    SSE2results_column2 = dr2["ordertype"].ToString();
                    SSE2results_column3 = dr2["ordercount"].ToString();

                    string SSE2results_rows = SSE2results_column1 + "#" + SSE2results_column2 + "#" + SSE2results_column3 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query2 " + SSE2results_rows);

                    if (SSE2results_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result2.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#" + "NULL3" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result in NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result2.txt", SSE2results_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query2 and written to file");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR2 ends");
                dr2.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR2 closes");
                cmd2.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd2 disposes");

                //###################################################

                string query3 = "select servicetype, ordertype, count(servicetype) as ordercount from ordermaster where "+
"CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created_date, 111) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-3, 111) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),created_date,"+
" 111) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-2, 111) group by servicetype,ordertype;";
                Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery 3 Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery3.txt isn't NULL");

                }
                cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con1);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd3 initiated");
                dr3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("DR3 executed");

                if (dr3 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader3NULL.txt", "DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DataReader3 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr3.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR3 read begins");
                    string SSE3results_column1 = "";
                    string SSE3results_column2 = "";
                    string SSE3results_column3 = "";

                    SSE3results_column1 = dr3["servicetype"].ToString();
                    SSE3results_column2 = dr3["ordertype"].ToString();
                    SSE3results_column3 = dr3["ordercount"].ToString();


                    string SSE3results_rows = SSE3results_column1 + "#" + SSE3results_column2 + "#" + SSE3results_column3 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query3 " + SSE3results_rows);

                    if (SSE3results_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result3.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#" + "NULL3" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result is NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result3.txt", SSE3results_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query3 and written to file");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR3 ends");
                dr3.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR3 closes");
                cmd3.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd3 disposes");

                //###################################################

                string query4 = "select servicetype, count(servicetype)as Active_count from servicemaster where servicetype='WLR Single Line' and linestatus = 'Active' group by servicetype;";
                Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery 4 Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery4.txt isn't NULL");

                }

                cmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, con1);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd4 initiated");
                dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("DR4 executed");

                if (dr4 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader4NULL.txt", "DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DataReader4 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr4.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR4 read begins");
                    string SSE4results_column1 = "";
                    string SSE4results_column2 = "";

                    SSE4results_column1 = dr4["servicetype"].ToString();
                    SSE4results_column2 = dr4["Active_count"].ToString();                    

                    string SSE4results_rows = SSE4results_column1 + "#" + SSE4results_column2 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query4 " + SSE4results_rows);

                    if (SSE4results_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result4.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result in NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result4.txt", SSE4results_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query4 and written to file");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR4 ends");
                dr4.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR4 closes");
                cmd4.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd4 disposes");
                con1.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection 1 ends");

            }
            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Exception1.txt", ex1.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Exception message 1" + ex1.ToString());
            }

            //###################################################

            con2.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection 2 opens");
            try
            {
                string query5 = "select servicetype, count(servicetype) as Active_Count from servicemaster where "+
                    "servicetype='WLR Single Line' and linestatus = 'Active' group by servicetype;";
                Console.WriteLine("ORQuery 1 Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query5))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ORQuery1.txt isn't NULL");

                }
                cmd5 = new SqlCommand(query5, con2);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd5 initiated");
                dr5 = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("dr5 executed");

                if (dr5 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader5NULL.txt", "DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DataReader5 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr5.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR5 read begins");
                    string ORresults_column1 = "";
                    string ORresults_column2 = "";

                    ORresults_column1 = dr5["servicetype"].ToString();
                    ORresults_column2 = dr5["Active_count"].ToString();

                    string ORresults_rows = ORresults_column1 + "#" + ORresults_column2 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query5 " + ORresults_rows);

                    if (ORresults_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result5.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result in NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result5.txt", ORresults_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query5 and written to file");
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR5 ends");
                dr5.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR5 closes");
                cmd5.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd5 disposes");

            }
            catch(Exception ex2)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Exception2.txt", ex2.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Exception message 2" + ex2.ToString());
            }

            //###################################################

            string database="wlr3crm_HQN";
            con2.ChangeDatabase(database);

            try
            {
                string query6 = "select servicetype, count(servicetype) as Active_Count from servicemaster where "+
                    "servicetype='WLR Single Line' and linestatus = 'Active' group by servicetype;";
                Console.WriteLine("HQNQuery1  Consumed");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query6))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HQNQuery1.txt isn't NULL");

                }
                cmd6 = new SqlCommand(query6, con2);
                Console.WriteLine("cmd6 initiated");
                dr6 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("dr6 executed");

                if (dr6 == null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("DataReader6NULL.txt", "DataReader brought nothing; check connection/query");
                    Console.WriteLine("DataReader6 brought nothing");
                }

                while (dr6.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DR6 read begins");
                    string HQNresults_column1, HQNresults_column2 = "";
                    HQNresults_column1 = dr6["servicetype"].ToString();
                    HQNresults_column2 = dr6["Active_count"].ToString();

                    string HQNresults_rows = HQNresults_column1 + "#" + HQNresults_column2 + "#";
                    Console.WriteLine("Result of Query6 " + HQNresults_rows);

                    if (HQNresults_rows == "")
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result6.txt", "NULL1" + "#" + "NULL2" + "#");
                        Console.WriteLine("Result is NULL");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText("D:/TOC/Debug/Result6.txt", HQNresults_rows);
                        Console.WriteLine("Obtained result from Query6 and written to file");
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("DR6 ends");
                dr6.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("DR6 closes");
                cmd6.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("cmd6 disposes");
                con2.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection 3 ends");

            }
            catch(Exception ex3)
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Exception3.txt", ex3.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Exception message 3" + ex3.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();               

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got typos in your code. You're executing the first `SqlCommand` multiple times:

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con1);
Console.WriteLine("cmd2 initiated");
dr2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

...

cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con1);
Console.WriteLine("cmd3 initiated");
dr3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Of course, you're also calling `cmd1.Dispose();` after executing it the first time, so I'm not sure how you're not just getting an exception...

You've also got some other typos in your code, such as the informational console messages you're generating before each database call:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query1))  // <-- should be query3?
{
    Console.WriteLine("SSEQuery3.txt isn't NULL");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for a quick response. I didn't notice that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-calling `cmd1` for commands 2 and 3:

```
cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con1);
Console.WriteLine("cmd3 initiated");
dr3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

Update it to be:

```
dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

and

```
dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your problem, use Copy/Paste wisely.

```
 dr2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
 Console.WriteLine("DR2 executed");
```

You have assigned the reader of cmd1 to dr2 and dr3. Please correct it to cmd2 and cmd3.

I have seen other errors as well. The code is not well written.